# FB.init (of Facebook web app) doesn't seem to get called when running on mobile

Tags: mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Facebook web app that runs on canvas. The canvas URL is configured as http://apps.facebook.com/myApp (example). This URL has an `FB.init` that helps me identify and login the user by getting his name and FB user id. This app runs fine on a PC or a laptop.

This page is very simple with some JavaScript but with routine HTML tags like `<p>`, `<input>`.

I configured the same URL as Mobile Site URL under Mobile Web. Since then I can now see the link for this app on my mobile device (an Android phone). But when I click on the link, the first page of the app opens in my mobile browser but it seems that `FB.init` can't run there. I can't get the user id and use name.

What is the reason and what is the solution, i.e., how to make the same app run on users' mobile phones?

Thanks.